# Rect selection after click selection 2.8.3

Tags: select

This looks like a very basic Question to me but I can not find an answer so far. Look at this image please:

[image: Click or drag select]

1. I clicked on the right cube and it is selected
2. I rect selected the left cube. Notice the dark selection color and:
3. there is still that "selection indication" in the outliner around the "triangle" in front of the Cube.001 name and the pivot seems still selected.
4. Now i click selected the left cube.
5. Selection indication gone. All fine now.

What does that red selection color mean (without selecting multiple objects)? I often run into problems, when that is active, since only the orange selection color is the right one.

Thanks